# Node* vs Node in main

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I am coding a binary search tree.

```
class Node {
 public:
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  int data;

  Node(int x) : data(x) {}

  void insert(int value) {
    if (value < data) {
      if (left == NULL)
        left = new Node(value);
      else
        left->insert(value);
    } else {
      if (right == NULL)
        right = new Node(value);
      else
        right->insert(value);
    }
  }

  bool contains(int value) {
    if (value == data)
      return true;
    else if (value < data) {
      if (left == NULL)
        return false;
      else
        return left->contains(value);
    } else {
      if (right == NULL)
        return false;
      else
        return right->contains(value);
    }
  }
};
```

When I use `Node x` in the main program and then call `x.insert(15)` it gives a segmentation error. If I use `Node* x=new Node(10)` and then `use x->insert(15)` instead then it works fine. What is the reasoning behind that?

```
int main() {
  Node x(10);
  x.insert(15);
}
```

Comment: which line it gives a segmentation error? I'd guess you just being lucky when you use new.

Comment: Side note: I don't think `NULL` is officially allowed in C++. I think it was technically replaced with `nullptr`. That said, I'm sure some compilers still allow it anyway.

Comment: @Chipster `NULL` is allowed provided you have `#include`ed one of the [headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) that define it.

Comment: @Ayxan That would make a lot of sense, actually.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you don't initialize the pointers (`left` and `right`) with `nullptr` but you assume they are initialized with a null pointer in `insert`. Doing the initialization in the constructor fixes the issue:

```
Node(int x) : data{x}, left{nullptr}, right{nullptr} {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped! Why does Node*x = new Node(10) in the main function, make it work without initializing left and right to NULL in the class?

Comment: @tylerdurden pure chance, the heap is more likely to contain `0` than the stack, in a lot of operating systems newly allocated pages are filled with `0`, if you haven't allocated and freed much memory (fairly unlikely at the beginning of the program) the heap will be full of `0`s. The stack on the other hand will have been heavily used by the runtime initialisation so will be full of junk data

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks! I did linked lists the same way, but now going through the code, I realized that in linked lists I was always initializing the next nodes in the member functions. In this code for binary search, I am accessing a memory that isn't initialized anywhere. Does the new keyword also initialize the left and right pointers to NULL even if I didn't do so in the constructor?

Comment: @tylerdurden no, `new` doesn't do any extra initialisation but as I said above heap memory is more likely to be 0 initially which is why it happens to work